# using javascript to display div based on option in select list

Tags: javascript, html

I have select lists where I want to display an abbreviated choice in the dropdown but display the full text below. I am trying to modify a javascript that I have used previously to display a text input when "other" is selected as an option. The select, the divs, and the javascript are dynamically generated in php. I have cut and pasted the php generated code into a plain html file to ensure that it is really this code that is the problem.

I have the following script:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">  
                function showreason() { if (document.getElementById('showreason').value == 'BLANK') { 
document.getElementById('showreasonBLANK').style.display = 'block' ;
} else {
        document.getElementById('showreasonBLANK').style.display = 'none';
    } if (document.getElementById('showreason').value == 'RECAP') { 
document.getElementById('showreasonRECAP').style.display = 'block' ;
} else {
        document.getElementById('showreasonRECAP').style.display = 'none';
    } if (document.getElementById('showreason').value == 'RETIRE') { 
document.getElementById('showreasonRETIRE').style.display = 'block' ;
} else {
        document.getElementById('showreasonRETIRE').style.display = 'none';
    } if (document.getElementById('showreason').value == 'ALTERN') { 
document.getElementById('showreasonALTERN').style.display = 'block' ;
} else {
        document.getElementById('showreasonALTERN').style.display = 'none';
    } if (document.getElementById('showreason').value == 'EXPAND') { 
document.getElementById('showreasonEXPAND').style.display = 'block' ;
} else {
        document.getElementById('showreasonEXPAND').style.display = 'none';
    }} 
function selection(select) {
    document.getElementById("section_" + select.value).style.display = "block";
}
            </script>
```

and this is in the body:

```
    <SELECT NAME="showreason"  id="reason_select"  onchange="showreason()" >
<OPTION  VALUE="BLANK"> Omit Reason </OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE="RECAP"> Recapitalization </OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE="RETIRE"> Retirement </OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE="ALTERN"> So owners can pursue other alternatives </OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE="EXPAND"> To allow the business to grow </OPTION></select>
</p>
<div id="showreasonBLANK" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="showreasonRECAP" style="display: none;">A recapitalization will allow current ownership to diversify holdings without compromising the company's flexibility to finance growth.</div>
<div id="showreasonRETIRE" style="display: none;">The business is being sold for retirement.</div>
<div id="showreasonALTERN" style="display: none;">While this business is attractive the current ownership is looking to concentrate on other business opportunities.</div>
<div id="showreasonEXPAND" style="display: none;">Current ownership believes that a new owner will be able to grow the business faster and take it to a new level.</div>
```

I am new to javascript so I have tried a few things that seem to make no difference. I have used onclick instead of onshow and used single quotes instead of doubles around the showreason().

No matter which option I select from the list none of the text for any div displays and I can not see why. Can somebody please help?

Comment: When I select an option the text between the <div> and </div> with id equal to the value of the select list does not display. I can't see why it does not. Can anyone tell me why the text does not display?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
document.getElementById('showreason')
```

in your conditions you should use

```
document.getElementById('reason_select')
```

because the id of the SELECT element is "reason_select" and not "showreason"

Comment: Thanks, that is correct but unfortunately it still doesn't work. That was an introduced bug from one of my many itterations at trying to fix things when I switched getElementByName and never switched back all the way.

Comment: I have finally figured it out. I named the javascript function the same name that I named the select. Looks like the problem was fixed when I renamed the javascript function so that it was named differently from the name of the SELECT.